# IPTables rules for LAN traffic

Tags: debian, firewall, iptables

As a learning experience I'm building a secure web/Email server on a Raspberry Pi V4.  I have it basically running but in looking at the sys/log file I see many records like the following:

> Jul 31 14:04:17 EMail kernel: [ 1023.038514] iptables denied: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:b8:27:eb:1f:9e:50:08:00 SRC=10.0.7.95 DST=10.0.7.255 LEN=78 TOS=0$
> $PROTO=UDP SPT=5353 DPT=5353 LEN=53

My LAN IP address are 10.0.7.0/24.  Is there an IPTables rule I can add for both TCP and UDP which will allow LAN computers to access other LAN addresses?  Is it safe?  Actually it is not clear to me why this Pi (10.0.7.92) would even be seeing this traffic? Right now I have these LAN based IPTables rules:

ACCEPT     udp  --  10.0.7.0/24          anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-ns

ACCEPT     udp  --  10.0.7.0/24          anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-dgm

ACCEPT     tcp  --  10.0.7.0/24          anywhere             tcp dpt:netbios-ssn

ACCEPT     tcp  --  10.0.7.0/24          anywhere             tcp dpt:microsoft-ds

Thanks for any comments and suggestions....RDK

Comment: It is not clear why you have rules about 10.0.1.0/24 while your LAN is 10.0.7.0/24. Can you explain?

Comment: It was a typo...

Comment: UDP port 5353 is usually used for mDNS. This is used by LAN hosts to broadcast their hostname to other LAN hosts directly. Key words are zeroconf, Apple Bonjour and Avahi daemon. That way hostnames can be known without relying on a central LAN name server. In your case NetBIOS seems to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This does not have anything with mail server. Port `5353` is often used by local multicast DNS services (mDNS). Notice target IP address ends with `.255`, it is likely the broadcast address in you LAN, so the packet was destined "to all computers" within the LAN. The system with IP `10.0.7.95` seems to support mDNS, so it sends this kind of packets. This is nothing wrong, and often desirable.

If you don't have an mDNS responder software on your server, you can safely ignore these messages. It might be a good idea to *silence* them, so important warnings won't get lost in the stream of this crap. For this, you can add the drop rule just before the logging rule:

```
iptables -I <chain> <N> -p udp --dport 5353 -j DROP -m comment --comment "silence warnings about mDNS packets"
```

To determine `chain` and `N`, run `iptables-save` (without arguments, it'll just print the complete running ruleset). In its output, find the rule which produces the log (the one which has `-j LOG` target), and then find out which chain it is in (the thing right after `-A`). That's your `chain` value. Then, you count its position in the chain, from the first rule with that `-A <chain>`. That's your `N` value.

The new rule will be inserted just before the logging rule (into position `N`, the logging rule will become the next one), so packets to UDP port `5353` will not reach it anymore and won't generate any such noise.

Alternatively, you can install mDNS responder and *permit* this traffic (by inserting a similar rule with `-j ACCEPT`, but I doubt you need that on the mail server.